# assembly instruction to offending C statement

Tags: assembly, gdb, segmentation-fault

Hello,

```
   0x08048981 <+1165>:  call   0x8048404 <printf@plt>
   0x08048986 <+1170>:  jmp    0x8048a52 <main+1374>
   0x0804898b <+1175>:  mov    -0x38(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804898e <+1178>:  mov    -0x24(%ebp),%edx
   0x08048991 <+1181>:  mov    (%eax,%edx,4),%eax
   0x08048994 <+1184>:  sub    $0x4,%eax
=> 0x08048997 <+1187>:  mov    (%eax),%ebx
```

How can i get the corresponding C statement for assembly instruction. The instruction at 
address 0x08048997 is the location of segfault as shown be gdb and i obtained the above assembly with 'disassemble' command in gdb.

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: Segfault at 0x08048997 means the address pointed by eax is not accessible/writable. Show us the source or the entire disassembly. What's in eax, how do you reach 0x0804898b just after a jmp?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using gdb, I'm going to assume that you're using gcc to compile. Add the `-g` flag when compiling and then load up your executable into gdb. I'm going to use this small program as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char *str = "hello";

   *str = 'a'; /* Will cause a segfault, trying to modify read-only memory */

   return 0;
}
```

ie. `gcc -g -o test test.c`

When I run the program in gdb, it'll crash and produce this output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400484 in main () at test.c:7
7      *str = 'a';
```

As you can see, since debugging information was added to the executable, gdb will tell you where the error occurred and show you the line it occurred at. I can also use `list 7` or `list *0x400484` to view the lines of code around the one that caused the error.

You can also still use `disas` to see the assembly instruction where the error occurred:

```
...
   0x0000000000400480 <+12>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
=> 0x0000000000400484 <+16>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rax],0x61
   0x0000000000400487 <+19>:    mov    eax,0x0
...
```

I think I made this post longer than needed... Long story short, as I mentioned at the start add the `-g` flag if you're using gcc to make debugging with gdb more efficient.